# Partial response in Spring MVC

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc

Our RESTful application need to support 'partial responses' to limit bandwith.
By this I mean that the REST client tells the URI service which fields of the resource it is interested in.

For instance: api/v1/users/123/fields=firstName,lastName,birthDate

We're using Jackson parser to convert our DTO's to a JSON structure.
The problem is that we cannot tell at runtime to 'skip' some properties.
We should need to create a class at runtime with a variable amount of properties to accomplish this. But I don't think this is possible in Java, it is a static language after all.

While searching the internet we found some semi-solutions by just returning a java.util.Map containing the requested properties or filtering out properties by the Jackson parser.
Especially the latter seems a 'hacking solution' to me. It seems that Spring MVC doesn't provide an out-of-the-box solution for this issue...

Is there any alternative in the Java world we can use to solve this issue?

Comment: usually sending a `Map` isn't that bad idea

Comment: especially since an entity composed of some selected fields doesn't represent anything concrete in your domain

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13792700/750510

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [Yoga](https://github.com/skyscreamer/yoga)

> Yoga extends JAX-RS and **SpringMVC** RESTful servers to provide GData and LinkedIn style field selectors.
>
> - **Choose which fields you want to see at call-time**
> - Navigate entity relationships in a single call for complex views
> - Much faster speeds in high-latency (e.g. mobile) apps
> - Streamline client development
> - Browsable APIs