# Java bean to JSON with selecting some fields

Tags: json, javabeans

I have Java bean:

```
public class User {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Address address;
    private List<String> favoriteBooks;
    private List<String> favoriteFilms;

    //getters and setter
}
```

I want convert instance of User class into JSON format, but selecting only three fields: id, name, favoriteBooks. I search some solution like

```
String[] fieldNames = { "id", "name", "favoriteBooks" };
JsonObject jo = new JsonObject(user, fieldNames);
```

How can I do it?

**EDIT** 
I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13792700 with using Jackson library

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I exclude fields with Jackson not using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764280/how-do-i-exclude-fields-with-jackson-not-using-annotations)

Answer (score 2):

You can try GSON library that allows you to convert beans to json and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

That's possible in Jersey 2 (MOXy or Jackson 2). For queries like this,

```
people/1234?select=familyName,givenName
```

it would return this json:

```
{
    "familyName": "Dowd",
    "givenName": "Andrew"
}
```

Find examples [here](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/tree/master/examples/entity-filtering-selectable).

Answer (score 0):

Using **jakson** library you can mark properties with `@JsonIgnore` annotation to exclude it from converting.