# JsonNode comparison excluding fields

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialise a JSON string using `ObjectMapper` (Jackson) and exclude a field while performing the deserialisation.

My code is as follows:

```
String aContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(aFile)));
String bContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(bFile)));

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider()
      .addFilter("_idFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("_id"));

mapper.setFilterProvider(filterProvider);

JsonNode tree1 = mapper.readTree(aContent);
JsonNode tree2 = mapper.readTree(bContent);

String x = mapper.writeValueAsString(tree1);

return tree1.equals(tree2);
```

Both x and tree1 and tree2 contains the value _id in the JSON String but it isn't removed.

Comment: `FilterProvider` is meant for Object, not `JsonNode`. Can `tree1` can be mapped to a Bean / Object ?

Comment: _id is key or value?

Comment: @ToYonos Nope, JsonNode is a completely dynamic JSON. The only static info about it is the _id key.

Comment: @user7294900 _id is a key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are following [Ignore Fields Using Filters](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization) except the first step

> First, we need to define the filter on the java object:
>
> ```
> @JsonFilter("myFilter")
> public class MyDtoWithFilter { ... }
> ```

So currently you supposed to add

```
@JsonFilter("_idFilter")
public class JsonNode {
```

It's not possible so you need to create a class that extends `JsonNode` and use it instead

```
@JsonFilter("_idFilter")
public class MyJsonNode extends JsonNode {
```

If you don't want to implement all abstract method define as `abstract`

```
@JsonFilter("_idFilter")
public abstract class MyJsonNode extends JsonNode {
}
```

And in your code:

```
MyJsonNode tree1 = (MyJsonNode) mapper.readTree(aContent);
MyJsonNode tree2 = (MyJsonNode) mapper.readTree(bContent);
```

Comment: How'd you make it work? 
ObjectMapper.readTree returns JsonNode, not ```MyJsonNode extends JsonNode```. I've tried this approach, and getting
```Error: java: incompatible types: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode cannot be converted to MyJsonNode.```

Comment: @AlexanderMelnichuk you can add casting `(MyJsonNode)`

Answer (score 2):

`FilterProvider` are meant to be used with custom Object like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764280/how-do-i-exclude-fields-with-jackson-not-using-annotations)

If you want to stick with `JsonNode`, use this method :

```
String aContent = new String("{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"_id\":\"id\"}"); 

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode tree1 = mapper.readTree(aContent);
ObjectNode object = (ObjectNode) tree1;
object.remove(Arrays.asList("_id"));

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(object));
```

Will print :

```
{"a":1,"b":2}
```

Comment: So, can I assume with a dynamic JsonNode object with a mandatory _id column, filterprovider will not work at all?

Comment: In my opinion, yes

Answer (score 1):

If you use Jackson 2.6 or higher, you can use a `FilteringParserDelegate` with a custom `TokenFilter`.

```
public class PropertyBasedIgnoreFilter extends TokenFilter {

    protected Set<String> ignoreProperties;

    public PropertyBasedIgnoreFilter(String... properties) {
        ignoreProperties = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(properties));
    }

    @Override
    public TokenFilter includeProperty(String name) {
        if (ignoreProperties.contains(name)) {
            return null;
        }
        return INCLUDE_ALL;
    }
}
```

When creating the `FilteringParserDelegate` with this `PropertyBasedIgnoreFilter`, make sure to set the booleans `includePath` and `allowMultipleMatches` both to `true`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonInput = "{\"_p1\":1,\"_p2\":2,\"_id\":\"id\",\"_p3\":{\"_p3.1\":3.1,\"_id\":\"id\"}}";

        JsonParser filteredParser = new FilteringParserDelegate(mapper.getFactory().createParser(new ByteArrayInputStream(jsonInput.getBytes())),
                                                                new PropertyBasedIgnoreFilter("_id"),
                                                                true,
                                                                true);
        JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(filteredParser);

        System.out.println(jsonInput);
        System.out.println(tree);
        System.out.println(jsonInput.equals(tree.toString()));
    }
}
```

prints

```
{"_p1":1,"_p2":2,"_id":"id","_p3":{"_p3.1":3.1,"_id":"id"}}
{"_p1":1,"_p2":2,"_p3":{"_p3.1":3.1,"_id":"id"}}
false
```

As you can see, nested occurrences of `_id`are not filtered out. In case that's not what you need, you can of course extend my `PropertyBasedIgnoreFilter` with your own `TokenFilter` implementation.