# How to globally apply @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "id" }) for all POJO classes of application (jackson api)

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

I have multiple classes and for all of them I don't want **id** field to be the part of my output JSON string (serialization). Let say I have 2 classes

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "id" })
public final class Person {
 private ObjectId id;
  //........
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "id" })
public final class Address{
 private ObjectId id;
  //........
}
```

Now I don't want to specify `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "id" })` manually on all my 1000 classes. Is there any global way to do, so that I can apply this part for all my classes? Very similarly like `mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)` in below method?

```
public String serialize(T dataObject) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();   
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(dataObject);
        return result;
}
```

**One way I tried is to make a super class and applied @JsonIgnoreProperties on top of that (which works). But still I have to write "extends" in every child class which I don't prefer. Is there any way in which I can apply this setting without adding anything additional in my pojo class?**

Comment: Not sure if this [How do I exclude fields with Jackson not using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764280/how-do-i-exclude-fields-with-jackson-not-using-annotations) answers your question

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just updated my description. I don't want to go to my pojo classes and add any additional setting. I am looking for something global.

Comment: The answer in the linked question seems to apply a global filter, or have I missunderstood something?

Comment: If i am getting this right i need to apply @JsonFilter on every pojo right???

Comment: No it seems that you just have to add 1 single class, from the example there: `@JsonFilter("filter properties by name")  class PropertyFilterMixIn {}`. I can't guarantee it though

Answer (score 0):

There might be more efficient solution but you might override default marshaller with the one which excludes unwanted fields but keeps all others.