# How to exclude specific field from ObjectWriter

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, jackson

The idea is to avoid the introduction of DTO. A user submits post request that shouldn't have `calculationSeed`. This field must be set by service and included into a response. `MapperFeature.USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS` not working. I am trying to avoid messy programmatic configuration [using filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13792700/480632). The problem is that `ow.writeValueAsString(john)` includes the field in **request** in JUnit test.

**Person**

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonPropertyOrder({"firstName", "lastName", "age", "calculationSeed"})
public class Person {
    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastName;

    private int age;

    @JsonIgnore
    private double calculationSeed;

    @JsonProperty
    public double getCalculationSeed() {
        return calculationSeed;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setCalculationSeed(double calculationSeed) {
        this.calculationSeed = calculationSeed;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(DataCollectorE2EIT.Config.class)
public class e2EIT {

    @Configuration
    static class Config {}

    WebTestClient client;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(ApplicationContext context) {
        client = WebTestClient.bindToServer().baseUrl("http://localhost:8080").build();
    }

    static ObjectMapper mapper;
    static ObjectWriter ow;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper().disable(MapperFeature.USE_GETTERS_AS_SETTERS);
        ow = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenPersonData_whenPostRequest_then() throws Exception {
        Person john = Person.builder().firstName("John").lastName("Smith").age(25).build();

        client.post()
                .uri("/api/persons")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(ow.writeValueAsString(john))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isCreated()
                .expectBody(Person.class)
                .consumeWith(result -> {
                    assertThat(result.getResponseBody()).isNotNull();
                    assertEquals(0.09482345680132348, result.getResponseBody().getCalculationSeed());
                })
                .returnResult();
    }
}
```

**logs**

```
> POST http://localhost:8080/api/persons
> WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]
> Content-Type: [application/json]
> Content-Length: [98]

{
  "first_name" : "John",
  "last_name" : "Smith",
  "age" : 25,
  "calculationSeed" : 0.0
}

< 201 CREATED Created
< Content-Type: [application/json]
< Transfer-Encoding: [chunked]
< Date: [Mon, 19 Oct 2020 15:26:01 GMT]

{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Smith","age":25,"calculation_seed":0.09482345680132348}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest solution would be that you change `calculationSeed` to of boxed type `Double`. Primitive `double` can not be defaulted to `null` that would be ignored so it will be *0.0*.

But more generally the issue that I have faced is that people tend to use the same DTO both for input & for output even if they are not the same as it seems to be in your case.

In your case it would be also easy to make two DTOs like:

```
// annotations...
public class PersonDTO {
    // all but calculationSeed
}
```

and

```
// annotations...
public class PersonDTOOut extends Person {
    private double calculationSeed;        
}
```

and then use these accordingly.